# Building 32-bit x86 executables on macOS 10.15 Catalina

Tags: macos, assembly, gcc, x86, clang

Right now I am dipping my toes in x86 asm, and am trying to build a simple program using the 32-bit [IA-32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IA-32). I understand macOS 10.15 Catalina dumped support for running 32-bit programs, but does this mean there is no way I can build them? What if I need to cross-compile for another system?

Here is what I am trying to do. Say I have

`test.c`:

```
int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

I compile with `clang test.c -m32`, and get the following warning:

```
ld: warning: The i386 architecture is deprecated for macOS (remove from the Xcode build setting: ARCHS)
ld: warning: ignoring file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib/libSystem.tbd, missing required architecture i386 in file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib/libSystem.tbd
ld: dynamic main executables must link with libSystem.dylib for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

When I try with `gcc-10 test.c -m32` (installed through `brew`), I get

```
/var/folders/pg/m7w7y_w94s32b23psmxmy7bh0000gn/T//ccwFWObO.s:5:2: error: instruction requires: Not 64-bit mode
        pushl   %ebp
        ^
/var/folders/pg/m7w7y_w94s32b23psmxmy7bh0000gn/T//ccwFWObO.s:12:2: error: instruction requires: Not 64-bit mode
        popl    %ebp
        ^
```

Am I completely stuck here? What would you recommend to get around this? Do I need to use another operating system (e.g., past version of macOS, ubuntu, FreeBSD, etc.) in order to build 32-bit executable? For what it's worth, I can produce an asm source file, calling either `gcc-10 -S test.c -m32` or the same with `clang`. I just can't build (and likely run) the executable. All suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Install binutils. You can use that to assemble. To run, use qemu. For C code you likely will need 32 bit C libraries though.

Comment: I installed `binutils` with `brew`, but it didn't come with any assembler (`as` or `gas`). I tried another one, `yasm` which supposedly supports the `gas` syntax but no luck there: running `yasm -p gas test.s -a x86` spat out a couple of errors, such as
`test.s:23: error: expected string`. If I can generate the asm source with `gcc-10 -m32 -S test.c` I should be OK in terms of 32 bit C libraries, right?

Comment: No, that just generates assembly it doesn't link. binutils definitely should come with `as` unless it has been specifically removed from what you installed.

Comment: I think you're right on the money there. It looks like GNU `ld` and `as` are [unsupported](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/17794) on Darwin/macOS. I am close to giving up on this, and am planning on using a different operating system. Thanks for the pointers.